# How do I get a specific file from the kernel's source code?

Tags: kernel, files

I need two files from the Linux kernel's source code, which I deleted by mistake:

1. `Option.c`
2. `usb-wwan.h`

I searched using these commands, but did not find them:

```
find -name Option.c
find -name usb-wwan.h
```

How can I get these files? (I do have access to an Ubuntu 12.04 installation disk.)

Comment: What location did you delete them from? Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Obtaining Linux's Sources (For Ubuntu's Downstream Kernel)

You obtained the kernel sources somehow. You should redownload them, or redo whatever you did to get them.

In particular, if you're running Ubuntu 12.04, and either you don't know how you got your kernel sources or you got them by installing a package whose name starts with `linux-source`, then you can put back any deleted file by completely reinstalling the package:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/linux-source-3.2.0/linux-source-3.2.0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-source-3.2.0
cd /usr/src/linux-source-3.2.0
sudo tar xvjf linux-source-3.2.0.tar.bz2
```

(Please note that it is intentional that `linux-source-3.2.0` appears twice in the first command, which removes the manually extracted source directory, if any.)

- You might also want to have the package `linux-source` (with no version number in the name) installed, so that you keep getting the source code for new kernels as they become available. But *reinstalling* `linux-source` with the above method will *not* replace missing files, as `linux-source` is just a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) that always depends on the most recent versioned `linux-source-` package in your Ubuntu release.

## Searching For Files By Name In Kernel Sources

Now you should have the missing files, so search for them:

```
find /usr/src/linux-source-3.2.0/linux-source-3.2.0 -iname Option.c -or -iname usb-wwan.h
```

Please note that I've used the `-iname` option, which performs case-insensitive matching. (`Option.c`, with a capital `O`, is a somewhat unlikely name for a source file in the Linux kernel's sources.)

The output will look like:

```
/usr/src/linux-source-3.2.0/linux-source-3.2.0/drivers/usb/serial/option.c
/usr/src/linux-source-3.2.0/linux-source-3.2.0/drivers/usb/serial/usb-wwan.h
```

**Please note that these files are from Ubuntu's downstream kernel**, patched (i.e., modified) specially for Ubuntu, and its parent distribution, [Debian](http://www.debian.org/). See [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) (especially [this section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile#C.29_Download_the_source_package)) for details. This is probably what you want, because it corresponds to the kernel that's likely to actually be installed on your machine. But depending on your specific needs, you might need a different kernel altogether.

Answer (score 3):

> *Note:* This answer most particularly addresses an earlier version of the question. This answer is still correct, but the question was made more general, so that it no longer insists on getting the file directly from other users.

Trusting files uploaded by other people for use inside your kernel is extremely insecure. Your best bet is to find these files on another system you installed and copy them yourself, or probably do a reinstallation.

Comment: Can you please give me these two files. I am in desperate need of them. Please!!

Comment: Though i understand your concern.

Comment: Kernel source code is available online. Go ahead and find them yourself - https://www.kernel.org/

Comment: I can't download theme, i am in need of them.

Comment: @BigGenius If you are in need of them, you would download them. Why can't you use official sources?

Comment: If you could tell me where to find them, i downloaded official source and didn't found anything. You should Research before posting anything "Useless"

Comment: @BigGenius Excuse me? "Useless"? I am asking a valid question.You have been given a link.

Comment: where is link? Fossy?